Правильная обработка ошибок в асинхронном методе. TelegramBot API
Я делаю телеграм бота, в котором бот отправляет уведомление клиенту о смене статуса заказа в другой программе.
Суть проблемы: если возникнет какая-либо ошибка от телеграма, то обрабатывается метод ErrorHandler. В нем я сделал MessageBox который предлагает перезапустить бота. И мне нужно, что бы при удовлетворительном ответе программа могла перезапустить бота или просто продолжать работать.
Решил проблему с помощью команды Process.GetCurrentProcess().Refresh();. Есть ли более правильные решения по перезапуску бота? До этого писал cts.Cancel(); и StartReceiving();, но он снова обрабатывал то же сообщение и MessageBox мог 100 раз вылезать подряд.
private async Task Error(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Exception exception, CancellationToken token)
{ 
     if (System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Ошибка! " + exception.Message + "\n\nПерезапустить бота?", SaveClass.NameApp, MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
     {
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().Refresh();
     }
     else
     {
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
     }
}


"Есть ли более правильные решения по перезапуску бота?" - конечно есть, у вас должен быть отдельный класс, в котором прописывается вся логика работа с ботом, ну и там условные методы Start() и Stop(), далее в случае ошибки вы просто вызываете нужный метод. Перезапускать целиком проццесс, это ооооочень странное решение, особенно в собственном коде, собственного процесса. Также замечу, что вывод сообщения, это тоже не лучшее решение, ибо данные должны общаться данными, а уже там где надо, делать на их основе вывод на экран сообщений. Другими словами, у условного "класса" должно быть событие.
